# Как клонировать поле из recordset DAO?

Tags: vba, ms-access

При считывании данных из таблицу надо скопировать поле из recordset в dictionary. Но это не работает, так как при перемещении на следующую запись в recordset поле уже не является действительным.

```
Dim d1 As Collection
Set d1 = New Collection

Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("tblPatient", dbOpenSnapshot)
Do While Not rst.EOF
    Dim PATNR As Long
    For Each fld In rst.Fields
        d1.Add fld.Name, rst.Fields(fld.Name)
    Next

    rst.moveNext
    Debug.Print d1.Items(fld.Name)
Loop
```

Как можно "клонировать" поле из recordset для дальнейшей работы с ним при перемещении указателя на следующую запись в recordset.

Comment: У вас должна быть еще одна коллекция для хранения строк -  коллекций с копиями полей, либо используйте составной ключ из номера строки и имени поля. И из кода не понятно, что вы хотите сделать, зачем помещать в коллекцию имя поля, а не его значение